# How can I install OpenJDK's Javadoc via command line?

Tags: java, ubuntu

How can I install OpenJDK's Javadoc via command line in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[openjdk-7-doc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/openjdk-7-doc). or [openjdk-6-doc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/openjdk-6-doc).

Comment: Sorry for so dumb question... :(

Comment: @PauloCassiano, if this answered your question, please click the check.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen the links say `Error`.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen dead links

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about Ubuntu but in Debian (Wheezy) the -doc packages only contain the documentation for Java, not the javadoc tool.  You need openjdk-[6|7]-jdk.